# How to Write Regex for Google Analytics Funnel Containing Dynamic URLS

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'm trying to build a funnel for pages with dynamic URLS.  My regex-fu is terrible.  I'm trying to see how users do on one of our wizards.  The URLS I care about all have each project's name in them.

```
/projects/<PROJECT_NAME>/wizard_steps/1
/projects/<PROJECT_NAME>/wizard_steps/2
/projects/<PROJECT_NAME>/wizard_steps/3
```

So I think I need to do something like this in order allow for these dynamic URLs.

```
/projects/?.*$/wizard_steps/1
/projects/?.*$/wizard_steps/2
/projects/?.*$/wizard_steps/3
```

Does this looks correct?  Any guidance would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
/projects/([^/]+)/wizard_steps/.*
```